# Which user should I choose when cloning Git repo into a non-user folder?

Tags: git, permissions, git-clone

Say I have the files on my webserver under version control and they lie in `/srv/web/htdocs`.

Which user should I best use to clone the project? The user I am currently using? The user who owns the files in this directory (`www-data`, in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a dedicated user, possibly a *technical user* or *service account*. Reasons for this:

- Limit the Git access rights of this user to read-only to minimize exposure in case of a break-in. Ideally, you'll never have to make changes on the server, so Git read-only access is sufficient.
- Have a separate password policy for this user, minimizing the risk of locking the Git account when the password changes. Ideally, you won't even store this user's Git password on the server.

In the best case, your deployment to this server is automated through something like Jenkins and Bamboo, and you can manage the Git user/password through that tool.

Comment: In my case, it's a staging server and I use Git directly to deploy new builds. I like how you can just test different branches very easily. I don't understand why you suggest only giving read permissions to that user. How could someone without write permissions change the source via `git checkout -b iss554` for example? Don't you need write permissions for that?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my answer. I meant read-only access to Git, not on the OS level. Sure, your OS user needs to be able to write to the local source folder - but he shouldn't be able to push changes to the Git remote. Sorry if my answer wasn't clear on this.

Comment: Oh, yes that's a good idea. I remember an environment I was working in a while ago, where it was set up that way now you mention it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the user you use for editing purposes/updates as well. 
Not sure if there is a well known best practice, but that's what i usually do.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense when you look at the problem in regard to workflow. It's just that it looks weird, when all the files and folders are owned by `www-data` and then the `.git` folder is owned by a seemingly random user. It feels wrong, but I have to admit, that it's probably the easiest solution.